# Correct way to set client in this Apollo syntax

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I can set client prop for Query element without problem.

```
<Query client={Apollo.localClient} query={...
```

but I can't get it working here, tried it in multiple locations:

```
export default graphql(SET_APP_STATE, {
    props: ({mutate}) => ({
        localSetAppState: appState => mutate(
            {
                variables: {appState},
                client:Apollo.localClient
            }),
    })
,options:{client:Apollo.localClient}})(App as any);
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to set it? normally it would be able to find the client by itself (from the context) if you are using the `ApolloProvider` component.

Comment: Yes I figured it out eventually. I'm using two Apollo clients. Here I'm trying to use the 2nd one (not from the context). The problem here is that this is set up when app gets loaded, but before *Apollo.localClient* is initialised, so it is falling back to context. Took me a while to figure out